# Copy files stored in VHD in azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

we have a azure windows vm which has couple of disks as part of azure storage attached to it.

As part of archiving the older data, want to copy the files to a local storage(on prem) and delete the files stored in those vhd's and thus reduce the size.

As you may already know , one way to do this is to physically copy the files from vm to local storage through a RDP session but this may be slow and may incur bandwidth usage cost.

I explored using azure storage explorer which uses azcopy in the background but i was able to see only vhd files. i tried to download or copy the vhd files but it fails after reaching 100%.

Please note that we're talking copying files of almost 500-800 GB to local storage.

Can someone please provide any suggestions regarding any better methods of copying these files.

Comment: Why do you want to download the files locally if all you want to do is archive the data? You can simply copy them in archive tier of blob storage.

Comment: Storing data in archive tier of blob storage also incurs cost. our preference is to not to incur any cost for this data. so, want to keep the files locally.

Comment: Why do you say that saving data locally is not going to cost you anything. You will have to pay for disks to store the data + pay for all the costs associated with maintaining these backups.

Comment: what is meant was that We already have an existing infrastructure and want to utilize that rather than provision or use anything in cloud.